# My HTML page is not coming up on localhost:8080 instead tomcat welcome page is displaying

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am new to spring and trying to build a simple application.
I have a simple html page(home.html) which gets called from Homecontroller.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

when i am trying to access localhost:8080 i cant see my html page instead i see the apache tomcat welcome page which shows - If you are seeing this page you have successfully installed Tomcat

what could be the reason for this?
any help will be appreciated

Comment: This needs more information: How do you build/deploy that code? Is it in tomcat's webapps/ROOT directory (or ROOT.war)? Or as webapps/yourappname - in which case it would appear at `localhost:8080/yourappname/`

Comment: Check your tomcat logs. You can find a line that the tomcat server is started with path `/your/path`. Check if it is the expected path. Otherwise, you can also check this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controllers#Controller).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tomcat you need to specify the **your app name** `http://localhost:8080/yourappname`.
Here the **app name** is the name of .war file.